# How to access an ANTLR4 rule reference without getting an error msg

Tags: antlr4

I have a rule like this

```
top_clause returns [TopClause tc] :
        tat = top_or_any_top
        SP
                e = expr
        EP
        {
                var ln = getLineNum($tat);
                $tc = new TopClauseExtant(ln, [...other params...]);
        };
```

Note I'm trying to get the line number and pass it to the AST object I'm creating. `getLineNum()` is

```
public static LineNum getLineNum(ParserRuleContext pr) {
        return new LineNum(pr.Start.Line);
}
```

`getLineNum()` may later get more from the token and return more, so I'm while I am getting an integer now (the pr.Start.Line) that may change and the return type `LineNum` (which currently just wraps an the int that is the line number) may hold more detail. Hence the `getLineNum()` func + `LineNum` class abstraction.

Unfortunately antlr complains: **missing attribute access on rule reference tat in $tat**. It basically wants `$tat.<something>` but I specifically want to pass the whole rule `$tat` so I can pick it apart more later.

Does that make sense? Any ideas on how to get what I want?

Comment: Try "$e.ctx". That should pass you the ParserRuleContext. See the table in https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md#parser-rule-attributes at the bottom. I'll admit, the syntax is inconsistent because "$e.v" in an action (assuming that you declared a "returns [int v]" for expr) turns into "_localctx.e.v", yet "$e.ctx" turns into "_localctx.e". Actions need to be comprehensively addressed in the next version of Antlr, 4.10.

Comment: @kaby76: certainly inconsistent but it worked, thanks! If you wish to C&P your comment into an answer I'll happily accept it. Handy link BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by kaby76; use .ctx, as in $e.ctx